# converting database data into json in codeigniter

Tags: php, json, database, codeigniter, model-view-controller

I'm having problem while fetching  data from database and converting into json using codeigniter. 
I've following database

```
create table todolist(
todo_id int,
todo_content text
)
```

with these example entity in database

```
1        assignment
2        lab report
3        notes making
4        preparing meal
5        cleaning room
6        feeding pet
```

I have written following function in Todo_Controller

```
public function json(){
$content = $this->db->get('todolist'); //todolist table name
echo  json_encode($content);
}
```

I'm getting following output

```
{"conn_id":{"affected_rows":null,"client_info":null,"client_version":null,"connect_errno":null,"connect_error":null,"errno":null,"error":null,"field_count":null,"host_info":null,"info":null,"insert_id":null,"server_info":null,"server_version":null,"sqlstate":null,"protocol_version":null,"thread_id":null,"warning_count":null},"result_id":{"current_field":null,"field_count":null,"lengths":null,"num_rows":null,"type":null},"result_array":[],"result_object":[],"custom_result_object":[],"current_row":0,"num_rows":null,"row_data":null}
```

your help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [result_array()](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/results.html#result-arrays) which returns the query result as a pure array. You can easily access your data from client side using [json_encode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php).

```
public function json(){
    $content = $this->db->get('todolist'); //todolist table name
    $data = $content->result_array();
    echo  json_encode($data);
}
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your code. E.g., what does `$content->result_array();` do?` Why is it needed to call it?

Comment: @Jost I have edited answer, it returns the query result as a pure array, so it will be helpful to access it from client side.

Comment: @SangamJungGauli if you find any answer useful or you get solution then please select answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
public function json(){
    $content = $this->db->get('todolist'); //todolist table name

    foreach ($content->result() as $row)
    {
        echo  json_encode($row);
    }

}
```

Try using loop and result function to fetch result. And its better to use active records queries in model.

You can read the documention for **Active Records** from [here](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide2/database/active_record.html)

Make a model and load it in your controller or if you want that model in all over your project then load it in autoload file.

Make a function on **MODEL** like this.

```
Public function getData(){
  $content = $this->db->get('todolist'); //todolist table name

   foreach ($content->result() as $row)
     {
      return $row;
     }    
}
```

And call it on your **Controller**'s function like this

```
public function json(){
$content = $this->YOUR_MODEL_NAME->getData();
$this->load->view('YOUR_FILE_NAME',$content);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

```
public function json()
{
    $sql = 'SELECT * FROM todolist';
    $q = $this->db->query($sql);

    //Fetch the result array from the result object and return it
    return $q->result();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [this](http://www.kodingmadesimple.com/2015/01/convert-mysql-to-json-using-php.html). Should work fine.

Comment: @SangamJungGauli glad I could help. You can rate the answer tho.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

**Model**

```
function get_people() {
  static $query;
  $this->db->select('id, name');
  $query = $this->db->get('people');
  if($query->num_rows() > 0) return $query->result();
  else return FALSE;
}
```

**Controller**

```
function index(){
  header('Content-type: application/json');
  echo json_encode($this->my_model->get_people());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this :

```
public function json(){
  $content = $this->db->get('todolist')->result_array(); //todolist table name
  echo  json_encode($content);
}
```

Comment: You can up vote and accept it as answer if it helped as it will help others too